# Why is the question about programmers qualifying for the .pro domain closed?

Tags: support, vote-to-reopen

I'm referring to [this question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/66544/do-programmers-qualify-as-professionals-to-get-a-pro-domain-name). It seems like a question with real answers to solve a problem that's only applicable to software developers. The only problems are the "should we?", the "thanks", and the poor tags applied, but if it's not going to get reopened, there's no point in fixing it.

Answer (score 4):

Whether one qualifies for a domain TLD isn't a problem specific to programmers, and doesn't require programmers to answer.

In fact, it's wholly answered by .PRO's [eligibility page](http://www.nic.pro/pro/eligibility.shtml):

> PRO is an exclusive top-level domain reserved for use exclusively by licensed business and service professionals and entities internationally. All applicants meeting the following qualifications may register a .PRO domain name:
>
> - Provides professional services
> - Admitted to or licensed by a government certification body or jurisdictional licensing entity recognized by a governmental body that regularly verifies the accuracy of its data
> - In good standing with the licensing authority

But beyond whether or not it's connected to the field, what exactly does it have to do with software development? Where's the expertise in going to the .PRO website and clicking on the link that says "Who's Eligible"?

Comment: Only in certain areas do people calling themselves software engineers have to be licensed by a certification body of licensing entity, and in others, they can't get a license if they wanted to. In North America, software engineers in most, if not all, of Canada as well as Texas and one or two other states need to be licensed, and are therefore clearly eligible. However, professional software engineers in other countries or states that aren't or can't be licensed might be interested to know if they can also do something to obtain such a domain name.

Comment: @ThomasOwens .pro domains are a general-purpose (not programming specific) product sold by RegistryPro: who qualifies and what licensing bodies qualify is completely up to them. Speculating about what might qualify and what might not is not constructive and off-topic: if a person wants to purchase a .pro domain, they should *contact the people who sell it* and find out if they can.

Comment: The answers are valuable to me, as a software developer looking to establish a strong web-presence for personal advertisement and professional representation, especially the ones who mention that they have purchased .pro domains using an IEEE membership. That kind of information isn't available on the websites of any of the .pro registrars that I looked at, nor is it on the RegistryPro website on any page (admittedly, I only looked at 6 or 7 of them, out of the page listing them). I just think that the sharing of personal experiences makes it valuable, since it's not documented anywhere.

Comment: @ThomasOwens Personal experiences of *what*? It's a sales question for the people selling the product. They [have an email address](http://www.nic.pro/contact/index.shtml) for sales inquiries: `sales@registry.pro`. Coming here to ask about it is exactly the opposite thing a person should do. *Contact RegistryPro to find out whether you qualify.*